# how does RHEL/CentOS 7 create the ifcfg-eth0 file?

Tags: networking, rhel, networkmanager

I replaced a bad NIC in a server with a new one.  After boot the `ifcfg` files under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` are no longer there.  **I did not delete them**.  Therefore I conclude that during boot RHEL/CentOS 7 at some point deletes them or will delete them; is this true?  Can anyone shed light on this?

- under **RHEL/CentOS 7.x** is what I am specifically interested in, but information on later versions is welcomed
- These `ifcfg-` files are obviously somehow created at install time from iso on dvd.  Is there any documentation or can anyone provide information on how that initial setup process happens?

  - the `ifcg-eth0` syntax is *deprecated* given biosdevnames and the *predictable-network-interface-names* stuff.   I don't like it - my servers at work are `ifcfg-em1` for intel, and my home pc is `ifcfg-eno1` and yet others show up as `ens11f0` (the list goes on).  If you had an `ifcfg-em1` file initially that is gone, how do you know what to re-create if you never knew it had the `em` syntax to begin with?  Or, when & where & how does that syntax come into existence in linux?
  - with my network down server not having any `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files I can still do `ifconfig` and have it list `em1..em4`.  How does it know to do that?

*I'll buy you lunch if you can tell me how to recreate and fix networking, completely, after purposely uninstalling all rpm's in linux and not having an `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` folder as well as all others related to networking... like doing an a `Minimal Install` at linux installation time versus `Server with Gui` or `Workstation`.*

Comment: Does your new device show up under `nmcli dev`?

Comment: `nmcli dev` reports DEVICE of `em1` to `em4` all with `STATE = disconnected` and `CONNECTION = --`

Comment: Can you try something like this? `nmcli con add connection.interface-name ens160 type ethernet`, `nmcli con up ethernet-ens160`. Then assign your IP.

You can also just use nmtui and do it via the terminal GUI, it's a bit easier for setting IP addresses if you don't have the nmcli syntax down.